# Why when changing the text in a textBox the forecolor is black and not green?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the form1 constructor i set the textBox forecolor to be in green:

```
cTextBox3.WaterMarkForeColor = Color.Green;
cTextBox3.WaterMarkActiveForeColor = Color.Green;
cTextBox3.ForeColor = Color.Green;
cTextBox3.WaterMark = "Browse To The File Location";
```

Then i have a button click event with openFileDialog

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Json Files (*.json)|*.json";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cTextBox3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                w = new StreamWriter(AuthenticationFileName, true);
                w.WriteLine(cTextBox3.Text);
                w.Close();
            }

        }
```

In the designer i set the cTextBox3 ReadOnly property to true.

The problem is once the text of the openFileDialog1.FileName is assigned to the cTextBox3.Text the text is in black. And i want it to be in green.
I tried to add before the line:

```
cTextBox3.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

All the colors changes like i did in the constructor to green i tried to set the cTextBox3 ReadOnly property to false set the colors again then set it to true again and still the text is in black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to visual styles. Unless you want to disable them completely, you'll need to also set the background color, for example:

```
tbx.ReadOnly = true;
tbx.BackColor = Color.White;
tbx.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```